# how to set a linear color to a shape in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, colors

have a good day, i want to know if there is a css code which change the circle shape color to black and white linear color, like the following image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YGia.jpg

Comment: Did you try https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp ?

Comment: See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "linear-gradient" for example:

```
-fx-fill:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #000000);
```

see the [Javafx Css Reference Guid](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)